# Serializing to JSON in jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

I know how to serialize an object to JSON in ASP.NET Ajax, but I'm trying to do things on the client in a less Microsoft-specific way. I'm using jQuery. Is there a "standard" way to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery supports no way of doing this out of the box. The best way to accomplish this is to use the JSON.stringify method in json2.js found here: http://www.json.org/js.html

This conforms to the ECMAScript 5 standard and will use the native methods if they are available.